# How to execute a method for each item in a listview

Tags: android

I have an `ArrayAdapter<MyService>` and to each item in `listView` I have one button that executes a async call to download a file by http request, this is working pretty well.

Now, I created a button "Download All" in the Activity, I would like this button to execute all items in the `listView`, but I have no idea how to do that. Should I iterate through the list, get the button view and call its click?

I would like to have some suggestions.

Comment: what's your problem - Executing all items in the listview or how to execute button on any item in the listview?

Comment: Why dont you just skip emulating the clicking, and simply call whats behind the click straight away. possibly in a loop. Maybe some code would give some more insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think iterating and faking a click is a good idea. I would just implement a separate procedure for "All" button that takes your data that is backing adapter (in your case it's array, right) and executes some logic to download it one by one or (much more preferrable IMO) in a batch, for example send file ids list to a server and make server return a ZIP.

Comment: Inside the adapter receives the array data, it iterates to each item and listen to some actions, in these actions, I notify datasetchanged, and I think your suggestion will working in this case, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think it's similar. Personally I would start batch processing outside of adapter, but I don't think it matters that much. If it is required, I would update your MyService items appropriately (I don't know, maybe you want to mark them as being downloaded or something like that) and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sample code which I used to Iteare the Click event on BaseAdapter

```
package com.nttdata.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nttdata.graphics.DrawShape;

public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context =null;
    private String[] categoryValues=null;


    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, String[] categoryValues) {
        this.context=context;
        this.categoryValues= categoryValues;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return categoryValues.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, null);

        // set value into textview


         ShapeDrawable sd = DrawShape.GetRoundShape();
         sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#33B2D3"));

        Log.d("DEBUG - CategoryAdapter",String.valueOf(categoryValues[position]));

        Button textView = (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.category_item_label);
        textView.setText(categoryValues[position]);
        textView.setTextSize(16);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33B2D3"));
        textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try{    

                        Intent productsIntent = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
                        Bundle param = new Bundle();
                        param.putInt("Categories", 1); //Your id
                        param.putCharSequence("CategoryName", categoryValues[position]);
                        productsIntent.putExtras(param);
                        MainTabActivity.productSpec.setContent(productsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                        MainTabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);


                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error in Setting Values to Product Activity ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("DEBUG_Dapter Exaception", e.getMessage().toString());
                }

               // Toast.makeText(context, categoryValues[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }



            });

        // set image based on selected text


    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;

    }

}
```

**Usage in Activity**

```
GridView categoryView = new GridView(CategoryActivity.this);
         categoryView.setNumColumns(2);
         categoryView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         categoryView.setColumnWidth(100);
         categoryView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
         categoryView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        layoutParams.setMargins(12, 20, 6, 20);
        categoryView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



        categoryView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(this, category_List));

        categoryView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                           CategoryActivity.this,
                           ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.category_item_label))
                           .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```